# How to dynamically import a module within a NodeJS script that contains path aliases defined in tsconfig.json

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-module-resolution

Our project uses React / Typescript and Nx with WebPack and Babel. Our monorepo contains dozens of applications. As part of our i18n initiative, I am working on a git hook that will scan each application directory and create a default `libs/pages/xyz/src/i18n/translations/messages-en-US.json` file that our translation team can ingest into their custom built system in order to generate additional files for other languages like `messages-fr-CA.json`.

Our first approach is for the Node script to find each root application messages file (ex: `libs/pages/xyz/src/i18n/messages.ts`), transpile it to ES2022, write it to a temporary file, and then dynamically import that file via `import(temp.js)` so we can do multiple transformations to that that JSON before writing it to the default `libs/pages/xyz/src/i18n/translations/messages-en-US.json`.

However, I am running into "module not found" errors when trying to dynamically import these files because each `messages.ts` file contains aliased import paths...

(ex: messages.ts import's from `common/foo/xyz` but in our tsconfig.json paths it would be mapped to `project-root/libs/shared/common/foo/src/xyz.ts`.)

Transpiling the code works fine when using `ts.transpileModule(filePath, compilerOptions).outputText` but when I try to `const module = await import(compiledJSFilePath)` I get module resolution errors because the aliased paths as defined in my `tsConfig.json` are not used when dynamically importing a single file with aliased imports...

```js
// my-app/src/i18n/messages.ts
import fooMessages from 'Common/foo/messages';
import barMessages from 'Common/bar/messages';
... other required imports ...

export default {
  ...fooMessages,
  ...barMessages,
  ... other message files ...
}

// extract-messages.mjs
...
import * as fsp from 'node:fs/promises';
import ts from 'typescript';
...
tsContent = await fsp.readFile(targetAppRootMessageFile, { encoding: 'utf8' });
jsContent = ts.transpileModule(tsContent, compilerOptions).outputText;
await fsp.writeFile(tempOutputFile, jsContent);

const { default: messages } = await import(tempOutputFile);
... do transformations here ...
await fsp.writeFile(defaulti18nEnUSFile, JSON.stringify(transformedMessages, null, 2));
... delete temp file ...
... iterate to next application ...
```

I am not a NodeJS / Typescript Compiler guru, so any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

[`paths`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) alias in `tsconfig.json` is only meant for the `tsc` compiler for types, not for the actually emitted JS code:

> Note that this feature does not change how import paths are emitted by `tsc`, so `paths` should only be used to inform TypeScript that another tool has this mapping and will use it at runtime or when bundling.

I guess your projects have a specific webpack path alias configuration, and the `tsconfig` just replicates those, as described in above quote.

Now IIUC, you are writing a new tool script, that will import your compiled TS file as well. Therefore you need to implement the path alias in JS side again. You could e.g. use the [`tsconfig-paths`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths) library:

> Use this to load modules whose location is specified in the `paths` section of `tsconfig.json`

Then when executing your new script, [enable tsconfig-paths](https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths#with-node) so that it adjusts node module resolution according to the tsconfig:

```bash
node -r tsconfig-paths/register extract-messages.mjs
```

Comment: I've gotten a little further in my research, so let me see if I'm understanding correctly... It looks like you are saying I need a custom loader to intercept and override the node's internal module resolution. I see this is done in the above lib by monkey-patching Module._resolveFilename, which I'm not I can use in our complex build environment. If I wanted to create my own custom loader to handle transpiling and path resolution, would I follow something like this? https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/esm.html#loaders

Comment: "_in our complex build environment_": if you do not describe how you use it, we cannot provide any more relevant help. That being said, if it did not need alias before, thare is no reason it would break because of these new aliases. But in the 1st place, sounds like you should execute that step as a separate process since you load arbitrary code that could have unexpected side effect.

Comment: I ended up switching tactics and leveraged Webpack instead of trying to run the typescript compiler directly... was much simpler, I just had to configure multiple outputs based on the entry paths...